# Socket io - rooms or emitting to individual sockets performance

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I’m currently building a chat application, where users can join group chats and talk to multiple other users in the same group. I use socket io rooms in order to organise the group chat between users.

Currently, when sending messages within a room, I use:

`io.to("group name").emit("Send message")`

This code sends the message to the entire room. The problem I have is that users only connect to a room when they click on the chat from the messages list (on my messages/chats page). If a user loads the app, and is on the home screen, and hasn't yet clicked on the group chat, they won't be connected to the room, and therefore wouldn't receive new events for that chat.

To solve this, the solution would be to send the event to each individual users socket instead of the entire room. This would look like this:

```
// Loop over all users in the group/room and send to their indivudal socket id, instead of emitting to the entire room like the previous code does

users.forEach(user => {
   io.to(user.socketId).emit("send message")
})
```

The question I have is that would emitting to the room directly be more efficient performance wise compared to the code above. If a chat had 100 users for example, would emitting directly to the room have performance benefits compared to the code above, which has to loop over all users in a room and send the data to their indivdual socket. With emitting directly to rooms, there is no need to loop over users and send to the individual sockets, so therefore it must be more performant than the code shown directly above right? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question I have is that would emitting to the room directly be more efficient performance wise compared to the code above.

No.  Emitting to a room (in the socket.io implementation) is just iterating over the sockets in the room and sending an individual message to each socket.  So, it's already doing exactly that.

The difference between your two snippets of code would occur if there are fewer users in the "group name" room than in your `user` data structure.  If that was the case, then sending to the room would cause fewer sends just because it contains fewer users.

> With emitting directly to rooms, there is no need to loop over users and send to the individual sockets, so therefore it must be more performant than the code shown directly above right?

No.  Emitting to a room just moves the iteration over the individual sockets to be inside of socket.io's Javascript implementation code instead of in your own code.  That iteration is still happening either way.  The bigger question is how many items are you iterating over because either way is still an iteration.

Comment: So in my implementation, in the second snippet, I am looping over all the users **within the chat**  which is the exact same amount of users that are also in the room itself. This means that in this scenario, there would be no difference whatsover between using the first and second code snippet, as either way I would be looping over the exact same amount of users. Is this correct?

Comment: @samalvis - Yes, if same number of users, then no meaningful difference as both have to iterate the same number of users and emit an individual message to each one.

Comment: So the only real difference performance wise could be if using the second snippet, if the users are objects which contain a socket Id property for example, and these user objects are large in size, i.e contain multiple properties, then this could potentially be less performant than emitting directly to a room, as a room just loops over socket ids and not large objects like the second snipped could be doing if user's are large objects.

Comment: @samalvis - There's no meaningful difference.  Trying to guess what a super tiny performance difference might be based on one additional property access is not advised, particularly when you haven't even compared directly to the actual socket.io iteration implementation code to know what it does.  But, regardless, this is like counting hairs on a gnat.  It doesn't matter.  The time for recipients to get a given emit will be completely dwarfed by the transit time over the network connection and the overhead at each end to send/receive each packet.

Comment: Ok, my only concern was the user objects are fairly large in size with around 100 properties per user object, therefore I believed looping over several of these could be less performant than socket io's rooms implementation for sending events to rooms directly.

Comment: @samalvis - It's not going to make a difference.  You're spending way too much time here on micro-optimizations.  That's just a waste of development time.  Write your code the cleanest, simplest. most maintainable way possible, then only work on performance issues when you have a proven performance problem and then test, profile and measure to find out where the performance issue is and what kinds of changes make a meaningful difference.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help.